# Jest test callback promise

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I want to test the following `storeCache` function. 
The critical part I want to test is the callback function in `Meteor.call(...)`.

I want to mock `Meteor.call(...)` but it is wrapped by a Promise and the callback itself also relies on the wrapping Promise.

```
 export async function storeCache(cache) {
    // do something
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Meteor.call("transferCache", cache, async (error, result) => {
        if (error) {
            reject(error);
        } else {
            try {
                const result = await persistCache();
                resolve(result)
            } catch (e) {
                reject(e);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

}

What is the best way to test the defined callback function via Jest?
Or is there a better way to structure the Code to make it easiert to test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's my solution:
The `Meteor.call` with its promise is in a separate function called `helper.transferData()`.
This removed the necessity for a callback. I can put the logic directly in
`storeCache()` and mock `helper.transferData()`.

```
export async function transferData(cache) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      Meteor.call("transferCache", cache, async (error, result) => {
         if (error) {
            reject(error);
         } else {
            resolve(result);
         }
      });
   });
}


export async function storeCache(cache) {
   // do something
   try{
      // call meteor method
      const transferResult = await helper.transferData(cache);
      // callback logic
      const result = await persistCache();
      // return Promise for compability reasons
      return Promise.Resolve(result);
   } catch (e) {
      return Promise.Reject(result);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be as simple as

```
// in your imports
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor'
jest.mock('meteor/meteor', () => {
  return {
    Meteor: {
      call: jest.fn()
    }
  }
})

//in your test case
Meteor.call.mockImplementation((eventName, cache, callback) => {
// your assertions
// you can call the callback here
// you probably want to mock persistCache too
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your implementation! But the main goal for me was to test the callback defined in my Meteor Call.